# Copying field from MSproject Gant view to Resource Sheet view gettign error 91

Tags: project

I have text data in Text field 1,2,3 & 4 on the MSProject (Online Desktop Client MSO V2302)  I would like for this data to appear in Text field 1,2,3 & 4 on the Resource Usage View.

I have VBA code to do this, but keep getting an error message: Object variable or with block variable not set (error 91).

(Sorry I am not a VBA programmer).

Can someone tell me what I have wrong?

Public Sub copy_task_location_to_resource_location()

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim t As Integer

For r = 1 To ActiveProject.Resources.Count
    'iterate through resources
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text1 = ""
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text2 = ""
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text3 = ""
    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Text4 = ""

    For a = 1 To ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments.Count
        'iterate through assignments
        'match up with correct task
        For t = 1 To ActiveProject.Tasks.Count
            If Not ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Task Is Nothing Then
        
                If ActiveProject.Tasks(t) = ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Task Then
                    'copy fields over
                    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text1 = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Text1
                    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text2 = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Text2
                    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text3 = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Text3
                    ActiveProject.Resources(r).Assignments(a).Text4 = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Text4
             
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next t
    Next a
Next r

Exit Sub
```

End Sub